# Image creating in PHP/Javascript giving a grey output around the image

Tags: javascript, php, image

Here's the link to and visit to see what I mean.

> **DEMO:** http://img01.fr/test4/

If I try to crop the image too small, it will output the right size and the right image, but you can see grey color around all around it.

I don't know how to change that, here's the `save.php'` that's called in the javascript:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    // image name
    $name = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

    // location to save cropped image
    $url = 'temp/'.$name.'.jpg';

    $dst_x = 0;
    $dst_y = 0;

    $src_x = $_POST['x']; // crop Start x
    $src_y = $_POST['y']; // crop Srart y

    $src_w = $_POST['w']; // $src_x + $dst_w
    $src_h = $_POST['h']; // $src_y + $dst_h

    // set a specific size for the image
    // the default is to grab the width and height from the cropped imagee.
    $dst_w = 240;
    $dst_h = 240;

    // remove the base64 part
    $base64 = $_POST['image'];

    // if URL is a base64 string
    if (substr($base64, 0, 5) == 'data:') {
        // remove data from image
        $base64 = preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $base64);
        $base64 = base64_decode($base64);
        // create image from string
        $source = imagecreatefromstring($base64);
    }
    else {
        // strip parameters from URL
        $base64 = strtok($base64, '?');

        list($height, $width, $type) = getimagesize($base64);

        // create image
        if ($type == 1)
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($base64);
        else if ($type == 2)
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($base64);
        else if ($type == 3) {
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($base64);

        // keep transparent background
        //imagealphablending($image, FALSE);
        //imagesavealpha($image, TRUE);

    }
    else die();

    }

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);

    imagecopyresampled($image, $source, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
    // save image
    imagejpeg($image, $url, 100);

    // return URL
    $validation = array (
        'url'     => $url
    );

    echo json_encode($validation);
}
```

I'd like to have only white around it, not this grey thing. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the image before copy–resampling:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);

$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);

imagecopyresampled($image, $source, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
```

I am also seeing that the JavaScript is passing invalid x, y, w, and h parameters that are then used by the PHP script to resize the image. For instance, I tried out the page and the following POST parameters were sent:

```
x=-297.61904761904765&y=-297.61904761904765&w=595.2380952380953&h=595.2380952380953
```

Because the input image is only 250×500, 595 is too large for either `$src_w` or `$src_h`. Negative numbers do not make sense, either.

Comment: Yes I tried that, it still gives the exact same output though :/

Comment: @user3807702: I added some more to my answer. It looks like the JavaScript is sending incorrect x, y, w, and h parameters to the PHP script.

Comment: I am so lost. I tried everything, but it seems that grey area is like a non existant area which is filled with nothing but still replaces the white background of $image.
The javascript negative numbers are meant to resize the image. The point is that one could resize the image and then click on 'crop' to have the image smaller in a 240*240 image with white background around the cropped image.